# Windows 10: Sort/rearrange icons in taskbar

Tags: windows-10, taskbar, icons, sorting, rearrange

I was wondering if there is an option in Windows, a tweak or third party software to allow arranging icons in the taskbar (currently it is possible only to drag a group of the same program, but not an individual tab, for example moving "This PC" to the left side before "Desktop" icon).

7+ Tweaker used to do that, but it is not currently updated, and the beta version isn't free now.  Any suggestions?  And also I do prefer a direct Windows tweak through regedit or something.

[image]

Comment: You can drag the icon left/right to arrange those. So why do you want to use 3rd party softwares?

Comment: no, I can't drag the icons.. what is allowed is dragging the whole group (same software), but when here are more than one open from the same software, they can't be arranged..  Or how do you do it if that is possible?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I'm on Windows 10 Pro 1903. 7+ Taskbar Tweaker can be downloaded from its [website](https://rammichael.com/7-taskbar-tweaker).

I've download version 5.7.0.4 Beta and it runs fine. The option was disabled by default for me. I did not find any requirements for purchase. However, donations are welcome.

[image]

Comment: 5.10.0.2 beta work like a charm, and seems to be free

Comment: unfortunately, the ordering gets reset if you are using a multiple virtual desktop program like Virtuawin. If anyone knows a workaround, greatly appreciated.

Comment: @tinker for fixing the virtual desktops order: https://superuser.com/a/1124627/269897

Comment: @Paul thanks for the tip, unfortunately it didn't fix the issue with Virtuawin. That's prolly meant for the native Windows virtual desktop.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to achieve it with [7+ Taskbar Tweaker](https://ramensoftware.com/7-taskbar-tweaker) is to enable **"Drag within/between groups using right mouse button"** and to drag items directly in the taskbar with the *right* mouse button.

[image]

Comment: Thanks..  But if there is a way to do it with an application, that would be great!